# query to search between two foreign keys in a self join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, foreign-keys, associations

Example data in User table
[image: image here]

Expected result in rails console, `father.children` and `mother.children` should return the same group of objects:

```rb
father = User.first
father.children
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 3, name: "son", father_id: 1, mother_id: 2>, #<User id: 4, name: "daughter", father_id: 1, mother_id: 2>]>
mother = User.find(2)
mother.children
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 3, name: "son", father_id: 1, mother_id: 2>, #<User id: 4, name: "daughter", father_id: 1, mother_id: 2>]>
```

This is my association now in User.rb model. It returns the expected result if I do `father.children` since the foreign_key refers to `father_id`. But it does not work for `mother.children` as it does not refer to `mother_id`.

```rb
 has_many :children, foreign_key: "father_id", class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :mother, class_name: "User", optional: true
 belongs_to :father, class_name: "User", optional: true
```

Is there a way for me to do

```rb
foreign key: "father_id" OR "mother_id"
```

I also tried having queries in the association, but couldn't seem to get my head around it.

```rb
 has_many :children, -> { where("father_id = id OR mother_id = id") }, class_name: "User"
```

Comment: What issue are you facing when using the query in the association?

Comment: I think this should work:  `has_many :children, ->(user) { where("father_id = :id OR mother_id = :id", id: user.id) }, class_name: "User"`

Comment: `User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_id" = ? AND (father_id = 1 OR mother_id = 1) /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]` this is what is returned. The problem is when I use query, it automatically does `WHERE "users"."user_id"` even tho I did not specify in query

Comment: Add unscope as the answer suggests below should fix the issue.

Comment: Yep got it  with `has_many :children, ->(user) { unscope(:where).where("father_id = :id OR mother_id = :id", id: user.id) }, class_name: "User"` Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unscope the default where that query creates, and then use the user id to filter the children rows:

```
has_many :children,
  ->(user) { unscope(:where).where('father_id = :id OR mother_id = :id', id: user.id) },
  class_name: "User"
```

Why `unscope`? Without removing it, your code will result in two SQL queries like these:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_id" = ? AND "users"."father_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1], ["father_id", "1"]]
```

When doing `User.first.children` - at least in Rails 6.1.4.

As you can see, the second query filters all those users with `id` equals to receiver (1) and at the same time, having the `father_id` column equals to the receiver (1). Which looking at your code, might never happen.

Notice, if you don't really need all those methods added to your model after declaring a `has_many` relationship, you might be better using a single instance method, or a scope (in the last case). Because using this approach, you override the default behavior (documented nowhere), that's filtering the rows in the other table by the primary key in this one.

Comment: Got it with `has_many :children, ->(user) { unscope(:where).where("father_id = :id OR mother_id = :id", id: user.id) }, class_name: "User"` Thank you so much!